# Run shell script in python to play audio file in OS X

Tags: python, zsh

I'm trying to run some zsh command in Python and I have a variable to input.I'm not familiar with zsh so I tried to handle it as in Applescript but failed.

```
wordToRead = getClipboardData()

p = subprocess.Popen(
        ['/usr/bin/zsh', '-'] + [wordToRead], 
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

scpt = '''
cd $TMPDIR
curl -o wordToRead 'http://dict.youdao.com/dictvoice?audio=wordToRead'
afplay wordToRead
rm wordToRead
'''

p.communicate(scpt)
```

Actually I even don't know what the zsh code do exactly.However,it will play a audio of wordToRead as result.

how to fix it?

Comment: Why do you need to use `zsh`, what is wrong with `bash` or normal `sh`? There aren't many differences for what you are trying to do here

Comment: @cricket_007 That's because I don't know how to do it with bash or sh :-(

Comment: So is your question what the script is doing? Or how to play the audio in python? Also, what is `getClipboardData()`? From what I can find, that is a Windows function

Comment: The main problem is how to input the wordToRead into the zsh script.But if the audio can be played in python directly ,it will be better. `getClipboardData` is a function I use to get the content of clipboard,it works nicely . You can have a look at this  [link](http://www.devx.com/opensource/Article/37233/0/page/3)

Comment: Okay, I was just making sure you were using OS X because of `afplay`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said, `zsh` isn't necessary, the default for the subprocess command on Unix systems is `/bin/sh`, which can run the script just fine.

```
import subprocess

wordToRead = getClipboardData()

scpt = '''
cd /tmp
curl -s -o wordToRead 'http://dict.youdao.com/dictvoice?audio={}'
afplay wordToRead
rm wordToRead
'''.format(wordToRead)

p = subprocess.call(scpt, shell=True)
```

> I even don't know what the zsh code do exactly

It is called a **shell** script, it is not "zsh code".

1. Goes into the `/tmp` folder

   ```
   cd /tmp
   ```
2. Downloads an audio file using the string you specify

   ```
   curl -s -o wordToRead 'http://dict.youdao.com/dictvoice?audio={}'
   ```
3. Uses the `afplay` command to open that audio file

   ```
   afplay wordToRead
   ```
4. Removes the downloaded file

   ```
   rm wordToRead
   ```